# Solr : how to use SuggestComponent

Tags: sql, solr, solrcloud

in my solrconf.xml I configurated this :

```
  <searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst</str>      <!-- org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst -->
      <str name="dictionaryImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.HighFrequencyDictionaryFactory</str>     <!-- org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.HighFrequencyDictionaryFactory --> 
      <str name="field">title</str>
     <!--   <str name="weightField">price</str>-->
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>

  <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="suggest">true</str>
      <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
      <str name="suggest.dictionary">mySuggester</str>
      <str name="suggest.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
      <str name="suggest.count">5</str>
      <str name="suggest.collate">true</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

and I tried to execute this url : `http://localhost:8983/solr/press-portal/suggest?suggest=true&q=tit&suggest.dictionary=mySuggester`

I should obtain the result but it returns 0 ....

Somebody can help me to understand?

Answer (score 0):

don't  forget to frequently build your dictionary by adding one more parameters

```
suggest.build=true
```

Answer (score -1):

Add weight field with new field name "popularity" type "long" indexed "true"
and try this request:

```
localhost:8983/solr/suggest?suggest=true&suggest.dictionary=mySuggester&suggest.q=t
```